# Use popUntil Navigator method with custom transition animation

Tags: flutter

I have 3 screens A -> B -> C. Screen B is pushed from screen A, screen C is pushed from B. My goal now is to call this method of navigator:

```
Navigator.popUntil(
 context,
 (route) => route.isFirst,
);
```

But apply custom animation like I was doing when pushing those screens. Example of animation I was using when pushing screen was this (where screen slides from the top):

```
Navigator.push(
  context,
  SlideInRoute(
    page: ScreenB(),
    direction: SlideInDirection.Top,
  ),
);
```

End result now is that I've made `FlipRoute` class that flips 2 screens, and I want flip to root.

Comment: Hey @Aleksandar, did you ever find a solution for this one?

Comment: Nothing so far that can introduce animation when performing the pop action. :(